# How to hide/show a div inside a parent div

Tags: javascript, css, show-hide

I am working on a site and I need to have a basic show hide functionality for part of it where, when the user clicks on a subject header, it displays an unordered list below the subject header, and then when they click on the subject header again, it will hide the content again.

I have done this in the past, but when I tried applying my code to the site I am working on, it does not work....the hidden content does not display.

Currently, I am using javascript, but if there is a better way, perhaps with pure CSS, that would be fine with me too.

Here is the code I am trying right now (I have a feeling that it isn't working becasue of a parent/child div situation, but I wasn't sure and so I was hoping someone could lead me in the right direction:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="toggle-buttons">
    <div class="web-develop-toggle">
        <a href="#" onClick="toggle-web-develop('web-develop-content',this)">
            <img src="images/subCtxHeader3-c.png" class="img-responsive" border="0">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="web-develop-content" style="display: none;">
        <div class="web-develop-body">
            <ul class="svc-list">
            <li class="svc-bullet"><span class="svc-list">Option 1</span></li>
            <li class="svc-bullet"><span class="svc-list">Option 2</span></li>
            <li class="svc-bullet"><span class="svc-list">Option 3</span></li>
            <li class="svc-bullet"><span class="svc-list">Option 4</span></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript that I am using currently, which has worked for me in the past, ironically enough:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function toggle-web-develop(id, link) {

    var e = document.getElementById(id);

    if (e.style.display == '') {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        e.style.display = '';
    }
}

</script>
```

Any and all help would greatly be welcomes as I have been stuck on this for a full day.
Thanks in advance!

-- Dan

Comment: Since you require the change onclick, you are going to have no choice but to use JavaScript.

Comment: One problem I see here is that you have `-` in your function name. This isn't a legal character for a function name.

Comment: Take a look at jquery and animate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `-` in a function name. Try something like `toggleWebDevelop()`

You are trying to find `web-develop-content` by id, but you are using it as a class in your HTML

```
<div class="web-develop-content" style="display: none;">
```

Should be...

```
<div id="web-develop-content" style="display: none;">
```

Also, I would use `e.style.display = 'block';` instead of `e.style.display = '';`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/vjVpd/1/)

Comment: This was it!!! AWESOME!!! I had to change the name of the function and then change the class to an ID, and it was smooth sailing from there. Thank you so much Schmatzy!!

Comment: Would anyone possibly be able to give me an example of how to do this same thing with jQuery animate? I'm not too familiar with jQuery but I would love to learn that functionality.